Differential Invariants of Surfaces
I'm reading Peter Olver's paper about Differential Invariants of Surfaces. In page 3, he defines two invariant differential operators $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$, and he adds -  "which are prescribed by differentiation with respect to the Frenet frame that diagonalizes the first fundamental form of the surface".
I wonder, is it safe to say that $\mathcal{D}_1$ and $\mathcal{D}_2$ represent differentiation along the principal directions?

It is safe : Nobody will sue you or arrest you over that.

@Prem Thanks for the funny note, but I would really appreciate knowing whether it is true or not, or at least a hint.

Just to note, perhaps Olver meant "...diagonalizes the second fundamental form..."? That would tend to confirm your guess. (In my view, any orthogonal coordinate frame "diagonalizes" the first fundamental form.)

@AndrewD.Hwang That's exactly what I have thought as well. Maybe I'll just ask him.

In another paper https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~olver/mf_/nfs.pdf (page 19) he states that: "... We let $\mathcal{D}_1$ ,$\mathcal{D}_2$ denote the dual invariant differential operators, which differentiate in the principal curvature directions..."

The use of “Frenet frame” is also an error. A Frenet frame is associated to a curve, and has nothing to do with surface geometry. Perhaps Darboux frame for a line of curvature?
